# Why MATLAB figure is different than Scilab for the same model?

Tags: matlab, scilab

I am simulating a nonlinear system of ODEs by using an ode solver in Scilab, but when I simulated the same model with the same initial conditions in MATLAB Simulink I got a different figure than Scilab. I would like to understand what the wrong, I am going to attach my Scilab code and the two figures (MATLAB and Scilab outputs). here in my Scilab code, I am using Q as a unit step input of the given system. I would like to simulate the given system in Xcos, Can I get any help? because I tried to use a user-defined function block(Sci-function) like MATLAB to simulate this nonlinear system, but it does not work.

[image]

```
clc
clear
t = [0:100/999:100]
function U=step(t)

n= length(t);

U=zeros(n,1);   

for i=1:n

    if (t(i)>20)      //step time

        U(i) = 2.2;    //final value
    else
        U(i)=2   //initial value
        end
end

endfunction
//call a unit step function 
step    
Q=ans      //a unit step input
function dxdt=f(t,x)
    S=x(1);
    X=x(2);

    dxdt=[(Q/20)*(0.02-S)-((0.4/0.67)*(S*X)/(0.015+S))
    (-Q*X/20)+(0.4*((S*X)/(0.015+S)))]
endfunction
t1=linspace(0,100,1000);
x0=[0.005;0.0101];
x=ode(x0,0,t1,f)
scf(0);clf(0)
plot(t1,x(2,:))
xlabel('time')
ylabel('X')
```

Answer (score 0):

The step should be computed within the right hand side of the ODE. If the rest of your ODE rhs is OK this should simulate what you want. Concerning your Matlab plot, the initial value was not the same as the one you used in your Scilab program (I fixed it):

```
clear
function dxdt=f(t,x)
    S=x(1);
    X=x(2);
    Q = 2; //initial value
    if (t>20)      //step time
        Q = 2.2;   //final value
    end
    dxdt = [(Q/20)*(0.02-S)-((0.4/0.67)*(S*X)/(0.015+S))
         (-Q*X/20)+(0.4*((S*X)/(0.015+S)))]
endfunction

t1 = linspace(0,100,1000);
x0 = [0.005;0.01005];
x = ode(x0,0,t1,f)
scf(0);clf(0)
plot(t1,x(2,:))
xlabel('time')
ylabel('X')
```

[image]

You can also simulate the system by using only native Xcos blocks :

[image]

You can get the diagram by using the following download link: [Xcos Monod Diagram](https://filesender.utc.fr/filesender/?s=download&token=df0a8cd5-c19b-41d7-8a07-a91fce9d2e39)

Comment: Can you help me to simulate the same model in Xcos and connect it with Scinote to plot the output?@Stéphane Mottelet

Comment: There is no connection between Scinotes (used to edit scripts or functions) and Xcos. Use the scope in Xcos to plot output of blocks. Please validate the answer before asking a new question…

Comment: Thank you very much @Stéphane Mottelet. We can connect Xcos with Scinotes by getting the output using to workspace block and then we can simulate by using these commands.  `loadXcosLibs(); 
loadScicos();

importXcosDiagram("C:\Users\82109\Desktop\staaaar\cont.zcos")
typeof(scs_m)
//importXcosDiagram(pwd()+"/Asserv_2nd_ordre.zcos");
        // Changement du contexte
        scs_m.props.context;
        // Simulation
        xcos_simulate(scs_m,4);`

Comment: Please have a look to the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Stéphane Mottelet for your help. This simulation by using Xcos and scope is okay, but I would like to connect Xcos with Scinotes file and use for loop to change the value of the gain K (K_vector), I am going to attach an example for this.[image: Xcos_simulation]

```
clc
clear
clf
// load the blocks library and the simulation engine
context.k=100;
context.tau=1;
context.tau1=1;
loadXcosLibs(); 
loadScicos();

importXcosDiagram("cont.zcos")
typeof(scs_m)
//importXcosDiagram(pwd()+"/Asserv_2nd_ordre.zcos");

out = [];
kvec = [1 5 10 20];
for k = kvec
    scs_m.props.context = [msprintf("k=%g",k) "tau=10" "tau1=10"];
    xcos_simulate(scs_m, 4); //Xcos_compiler
    out = [out sim.values(:,2)];
end

in  = sim.values(:,1)
t = sim.time
scf(0);clf(0)
plot(t,in,t,out)
legend("in","out, k="+string(kvec))
```

Comment: In the Monod diagram, which context variable do you want to change in the loop ?

Comment: I would like to change the gain k=k_vec[1 5 10 20] and plot the output and the unit step input in the same figure.

Comment: Sorry, there is no identified gain in your Monod code, just a lot of constants (besides Q).

Comment: Context.k=10, this the gain value. I would like to replace it with  k=k_vec[1 5 10 20] in for loop.

Comment: I edited your code above, it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Mottelet. It works perfectly.

Comment: OK great, can you validate the answers then ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Thanks.